# What hardware problem does a video signal shift on hard lock imply?

Tags: freebsd, hardware, freeze, crash, pfsense

I'm running a pfsense router on a PC architecture desktop system (AMD FX-8120 CPU with 16GB RAM). It's running version pfsense version 2.7.0, which is based on FreeBSD v14.

Every day or two the router has been hard locking in a way that the keyboard doesn't work and the video signal on the screen continues to show the text part of the console, but creates a slight visible ghosting effect between the red and blue channels, almost like they got out of sync. The video effect is kinda subtle, but it always happens after this type of hard lock. What I'm wondering is if this kind of hard lock indicates that a specific hardware component has gone bad (CPU, RAM, motherboard, hard drive, video card, secondary network card, PSU, etc). This system doesn't have a separate video card though.

I don't think this is something specific to FreeBSD as I've seen this behavior on a malfunctioning Linux system as well. I plan to replace the whole guts of the system soon to fix the problem in one go, just wondering if that specific symptom tracks back to a specific component.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this should be asked on [su] as it's about hardware.